# How to program Java app to execute everyday at a certain time?

Tags: java, windows-7

My computer is turned on 7/24. However, it does gets locked. I have an app that includes `Selenium` and other APIs. I need it to execute everyday at say 6 AM. Is there any way I could do this. I heard about the Windows Scheduler. Is there any way to make it execute on its own? Or waht is the best way to do this. (I have Windows 7)

Comment: `"I heard about the Windows Scheduler. Is there any way to make it execute on its own?"` Yes, that's the whole point.'

Comment: I don't know which kind of SSCCE somebody would need to replicate this problem =S

Comment: Refer to: [Windows 7: Schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task). Create a task that will execute your java applcations through command e.g. `java MainClass` (of course, the command may be more complex than this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Quartz scheduler. Please find the link for the same : http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Using quartz scheduler you can schedule a job to run everyday at 6 AM using cron expressions. You can create cron expressions using [www.cronmaker.com](http://www.cronmaker.com)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I do not get what you mean by your comment

Comment: I mean: to use quartz you will need it to be running inside a Java application, thus the application must be running all day, but if an unhandled exception raises and the JVM application exists then the cron will stop working. In this case, it will be better to rely on OS settings instead of having an eternal Java application that will call another Java applications.

Comment: The only use case when I could come up to use quartz to solve this specific problem is that OP should launch several process in the same date, but still, IMO it will still be better configuring the tasks on OS.

Comment: My first comment contains a mistake: is not about *how to use*, is about *when to use*.

Comment: The question doesn't explicitly specify either way; however I assumed the question was asking to START/Execute an application everyday at 6AM based on wording. However, if the App run's 24/7 and the requirement is to execute some method at a specific time, quartz could be an option. I've seen quartz used more when a method needs executing at a specific time, rather than a whole application.

Comment: @MattJones *I have an app that includes Selenium and other APIs. I need it to execute everyday at say 6 AM.* There's no app running 24/7, just the PC (probably a server) is turned on all day.